# Waitforstatus service powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have written a script to stop the services on any server!
But I get error:

```
      YMethod invocation failed because[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus] does not contain a method   named 'WaitForStatus'.
    At C:\Admin\Scripts\JBoss_StartStopp\stoppa_alla_IX2 och IX3.ps1:18 char:7
    +       $getservicestatus.WaitForStatus("Stopped")
    +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

When you quit a service on a server, I want to wait until the service is stopped and then go to the next service on the next server!

```
   $serverlist = Get-Content “.\server.txt”
   $servicename = "JBoss_cambio"

   $serverlistIX3 = Get-Content “.\ix3.txt”
   $servicenameIX3 = "Laskopia_Cosmic"


  foreach ($server in $serverlist) {

$getservicestatus = (Get-Service -Name $servicename -ComputerName $server).status
if ($getservicestatus -eq "Running") {
  Set-Service -Name $servicename -ComputerName $server -Status Stopped

  $getservicestatusIX3.WaitForStatus("Stopped")

  Write-Host "$server $servicename Stoppad!" -ForegroundColor Green
  }
else
  {
  Write-Host "$server $servicename var redan Stopped!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
  }
}


   foreach ($server in $serverlistIX3) {

$getservicestatusIX3 = (Get-Service -Name $servicenameIX3 -ComputerName $server).status
if ($getservicestatusIX3 -eq "Running") {
  Set-Service -Name $servicenameIX3 -ComputerName $server -Status Stopped
  $getservicestatusIX3.WaitForStatus("Stopped")
  Write-Host "$server $servicenameIX3 Sttopad!" -ForegroundColor Green
  }
else
  {
  Write-Host "$server $servicenameIX3 var redan Stoppad!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
  }
}


    Write-Host "." -ForegroundColor DarkBlue
     Read-Host "Tryck ENTER för att avsluta"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `WaitForStatus` method is member of `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` class, not `ServiceControllerStatus`. For example:

```
$s = Get-Service spooler
$s.WaitForStatus("Stopped")
```

You could modify your code to something like this:

```
$serviceIX3 = Get-Service -Name $servicenameIX3 -ComputerName $server
if($serviceIX3.status -eq "Running") {
    Stop-Service $serviceIX3
    $serviceIX3.WaitForStatus("Stopped")
    Write-Host "$server $servicenameIX3 Sttopad!" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: How can I see that it is checking the status until it stops ?! I want to see it waiting for the stop status.

Comment: You're right. Edited the code to use `Stop-Service`

Comment: what do you mean?!

Comment: Suggest using the service status enum instead of the string literal ("Stopped"):
[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped

Answer (score 2):

Your `$getservicestatus` is a [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus(v=vs.110).aspx) and not a [ServiceController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

This `getservicestatus` doesn't have `WaitForStatus` method.

Try this

```
$getservice = Get-Service -Name $servicename -ComputerName $server
```

And now you can use `$getservices.WaitForStatus("Stopped")`

```
Write-Output "We stop the service: $servicename"
Stop-Service -Name $servicename
$getservice.WaitForStatus("Stopped")
Write-Output "$servicename Stoped"
```

Comment: ow can I see that it is checking the status until it stops ?! I want to see it waiting for the stop status.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use a time-span parameter, wait will continually test every 1/4 second or so and may inadvertently wait forever.